# Ajax error when attempting component updates

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am having a couple of issues with a Joomla 3.6 site that I maintain.

Issue 1 is with the Joomla update component. When the update attempts to run it gets an Ajax alert error, and the following error in console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/administrator/components/com_joomlaupdate/restore.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The second issue is with uploading images. Whenever I try to upload an image either in the media manager, an article or module, the site acts like it's uploading the image, refreshes, but never actually uploads the image.

I have error reporting turned on maximimum and still no errors after the routine finishes. I have to say I am completely beside myself as to what is going on.

**UPDATE**
the php error log reads:

```
[08-Sep-2016 03:45:49 America/Chicago] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: result in /mnt/stor1-wc2 dfw1/417008/591382/www.example.com/web/content/libraries/joomla/mail/mail.php on line 479
```

Comment: Please don't ask two completely separate questions in one post. Edit to remove one of them.

Comment: Also, since this isn't a code question, try http://joomla.stackexchange.com.

Comment: yes well i am pretty certain the two issues are related,

Comment: I'd be inclined to overwrite the entire Joomla core install. You can do so right from the update tool  now. If that doesn't fix it, you have some obscure server config issue that we can't know anything about.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the Joomla Update tool that is failing for me. Possibly upload the install package minus the installation folder?

Comment: Right. That's how it's always been done until recently.

Comment: <<Pounding head against the wall>> the one and only client i don't host on my own box and only have FTP access to. Fun times!

Comment: No fun. I won't do Joomla work without host access. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Re. Your Ajax issue -

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/administrator/components/com_joomlaupdate/restore.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

It's clearly a cross origin issue. You should add `www` in the ajax url or remove from domain. It would be better if you get ajx url dynamically from JS. So if `www` in the domain add that to Ajax request otherwise not.

2)Re. upload issue - You should check folder permissions. This might be due to not having proper permission to size limit. One can check permission under `Folder Permissions` tab from below url(make sure to change host).

http://www.example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_admin&view=sysinfo